# Systemd service generating Environment File for another one

Tags: systemd, services

I have coded two systemd scripts, "`A`" and "`B`". `B` starts after `A` using the `After` clause.

`A` produces an `input.txt` that `B` uses as EnvironmentFile.

The problem I am facing is on the first boot.

During the first boot, `input.txt` does not yet exist, It will be generated after `A` launches.

So I think systemds works in a way that needed files are tried to be fetched before the actual programs in services launch (maybe I should change `B` systemd type?)

In fact, during the first boot, I have an "Environment File not found" error in `B` service status.

So what I think happens is: `A` and `B` services are evaluated firstly and since input.txt does not yet exist, `B` is evaluated as failed, but after `A` execution, `input.txt` file is correctly created.

For each subsequent reboot, `input.txt` exists (it is changed by `A` if exists, or created by `A` if it is not present on disk), `B` finds it and correctly executes.

My question is: how can I make these scripts work even at first boot?

Comment: can you just include an empty "input.txt" file, and in your B script test if that file is not empty before working on it?